# 2-е свойство REST

Tags: веб-программирование, rest, веб-сервер, сессия, клиент-сервер

Изучаю что такое REST. Нашел статью про [REST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST). Во 2-м свойстве REST написано

> Протокол взаимодействия между клиентом и сервером требует соблюдения следующего условия: в период между запросами клиента никакая информация о состоянии клиента на сервере не хранится (Stateless protocol или «протокол без сохранения состояния»).

но с другой стороны также написано, что

> Состояние сессии при этом сохраняется на стороне клиента. Информация о состоянии сессии может быть передана сервером какому-либо другому сервису (например, в службу базы данных) для поддержания устойчивого состояния, например, на период установления аутентификации. Клиент инициирует отправку запросов, когда он готов (возникает необходимость) перейти в новое состояние.

Т.е. получается (из 2-й цитаты), что Состояние сессии может храниться на сервере, но с другой стороны

> в период между запросами клиента никакая информация о состоянии клиента на сервере не хранится (Stateless protocol или «протокол без сохранения состояния»)

т.е. информация о состояние клиента не может храниться на сервере. Но как я понимаю информация о состоянии сессии включает в себя информацию о состоянии клиента. Получается противоречие. Проясните пожалуйста этот момент (может это 2-е свойство не точно изложено - тогда приведите другую формулировку с другого ресурса). Объясните пожалуйста 2-е свойство REST.

Answer (score 1):

> Информация о состоянии сессии может быть передана сервером какому-либо другому сервису

Это предложение говорит лишь о передаче, не о хранении, поэтому противоречия нет. Состояние хранится на клиенте и необходимые куски при каждом запросе передаются серверу, а сервер уже дальше получив это состояние от клиента может использовать его

Comment: ты написал, что "и необходимые куски при каждом запросе передаются серверу", но с другой стороны в Википедии написано, что " в период между запросами клиента никакая информация о состоянии клиента на сервере не хранится (Stateless protocol или «протокол без сохранения состояния»)". Противоречие.

Comment: на сервере не хранится, но это не мешает ему получать и использовать информацию при каждом запросе.
 Даже аутентификация происходит при каждом запросе заного через токены ключи или даже просто с логином и паролем (но так лучше не делать)